# How to ignore/disable system font size when load page inside webview_flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-web, webview-flutter

I have an application that adds `webview_flutter` to show some certain page. When I change the system font size on an Android device, the page inside the WebView widget follows the android system font size. How can I ignore/disable the page inside the WebView to follow the system font size?

I have tried to add MediaQuery to set globally to ignore the scale font size (something like [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22480)). The flutter app itself ignores the scale, but not on the page inside the WebView widget.

Comment: I think the WebView component is controlled directly by the system, so perhaps that's why it gets affected when you're trying to change things in the system, such as setting the system-wide font size.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?